# Issue updating a <div> via AJAX refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am dynamically generating a web page via scriptA.php.  Within this page,
I have a div element #WatchContainer that needs to be updated every 5 minutes. The content for #WatchContainer is created by scriptB.php.  To accomplish this, I have used "include" to embed scriptB.php in scriptA.php.  The variable $sum is defined in scriptA.php and used by scriptB.php to update the content in #WatchContainer.

On initial page load, $sum is correctly passed from scriptA.php to scriptB.php. However, when #WatchContainer is updated via AJAX request, $sum is no longer passed to scriptb.php.  The jQuery function is as follows:

```
function updateWatch() {
  $.ajax({
      url:"scriptB.php",
      success: function(data) {
             $("#WatchContainer").html(data);
      }
    });
}

var WatchInterval = setInterval("updateWatch()", 300000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't see you passing any variable to scriptB.php via ajax.
 i thinnk you should pass your $sum variable to scriptB.php via ajax using POST OR GET method

---

POST

```
function updateWatch(sum) {
  $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"scriptB.php",
      data:"sum="+sum,
      success: function(data) {
             $("#WatchContainer").html(data);
      }
    });
}
```

---

GET

```
function updateWatch(sum) {
  $.ajax({
      type:"GET",
      url:"scriptB.php?sum="+sum,
      success: function(data) {
             $("#WatchContainer").html(data);
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with 3 seconds interval time, and make sure you include the library and other related stuff.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var WatchInterval = setInterval(function() {
             $.ajax({
                url:"scriptB.php",
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    }
             });
        },3000);
    });
<script>
```

Comment: I have set the interval to update as frequently as 10 seconds to test with no success.

Comment: The function works.  I have used an alert to signal its execution, which displays in the browser.  When I echo the value of $sum, it correctly displays on initial page load.  However, after the AJAX call, $sum is empty.

Comment: @user1985891 try without interval and tell me if it works without interval

Comment: Yes, the alert pops up every 3 seconds.  No refresh without the interval.

Comment: @user1985891 so you get the alert, but not the refresh?

Comment: You defined the $sum variable in scriptA.php thus it is not available in scriptB.php that you are making the AJAX call to.

Comment: @user1985891 as bagonyi said, you are making a fatal error. The variable $sum is defined in scriptA.php and used by scriptB.php to update the content in #WatchContainer.

Comment: Yes, but through the "include" line in scriptA.php, $sum is being passed to scriptB.php.  And as I mention, the value of $sum is showing up correctly in the content created by scriptB.php on initial page load.

Comment: Using an AJAX POST to pass $sum worked.  Thanks much for the help!